# error: { code: -32000, message: 'invalid sender' }

Tags: solidity, rinkeby, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I'm trying to deploy my Smart Contract onto the Rinkeby test network. Everything is working fine, my rinkeby account is also having enough ethers. And also using HDWalletProvider, I am able to access my rinkeby account as it's getting logged out on the terminal too but still I am getting this error don't know why

My abi and bytecode are also working fine as previously I deployed the same contract on my ganache local network. Only when deploying it on rinkeby, I'm facing this issue.

Also if I don't use try and catch, some really really huge chunk of characters keep printing on my terminal. I have no clue what's the real problem here.

[image]

Comment: You're deploying from your second account (`account[1]`), not your first account (`account[0]`). Is that intentional?

Comment: No so sorry.. that was just a typo
The error still remains there when I'm using accounts[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure  HDWalletProvider is updated to latest and then pass the chainId as an option to HDWalletProvider. For rinkeby its `4`.

The next version of HDWalletProvider will auto fetch the chainId,  but it doesn't do this yet. This feature will likely will be released next Thursday or Friday.

This only started happening now because geth recently began defaulting to requiring eip-155 style transactions, i.e., with replay protection.

Comment: Thanx a lot.. it finally worked !!
But just out of curiosity I would like to know what was being printed on my terminal when I wasn't using try catch. It was some really huge chunk of characters through.